# Change part of a word (string) into in a different string if a sign occurs. Python

Tags: python

How most effectively do I cut out a part of a word if the character '`=#=`' appears and then finish cutting the word if the character '`=#=`' appears? For example:

From a large string

```
'321@5=85@45@41=#=I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW=#=3234@41@=q#$^1=@=xx$q=@=xpa$=4319'
```

The python code returns:

```
'I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split()`:

```
s = '321@5=85@45@41=#=I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW=#=3234@41@=q#$^1=@=xx$q=@=xpa$=4319'

st = '=#='
ed = '=#='
print((s.split(st))[1].split(ed)[0])
```

Using `regex`:

```
import re
s = '321@5=85@45@41=#=I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW=#=3234@41@=q#$^1=@=xx$q=@=xpa$=4319'

print(re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (st, ed), s).group(1))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @DirtyBit's answer, if you want to also handle cases of more than 2 '=#='s, you can split the string, and then add every other element:

```
s = '321@5=85@45@41=#=I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW=#=3234@41@=q#$^1=@=xx$q=@=xpa$=4319=#=|I-ALSO-LOVE-SO=#=3123123'
parts = s.split('=#=')
print(''.join([parts[i] for i in range(1,len(parts),2)]))
```

## Output

```
I-LOVE-STACK-OVER-FLOW|I-ALSO-LOVE-SO
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the code.

```
import re


ori_list = re.split("=#=",ori_str)
    # you can imagine your goal is to find the string wrapped between signs of "=#=" 
    # so after the split, the even number position must be the parts outsides of "=#=" 
    # and the odd number position is what you want
for i in range(len(ori_list)):
    if i%2 == 1:#odd position
       print(ori_list[i])
```